# Transfer settings from Lollipop to Marshmallow (with EMUI)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, data-transfer

I am migrating from a Samsung S6 (`Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow`) to a Huawei Ascent Mate 8 (`Android 6.0 Marshmallow`).

On the Huawei Phone, I am not prompted for a Google Login or the option to synchronise data with Tap&Go.

Are these peculiar features of EMUI or is it not possible to use Tap&Go from `Android 6.0.1` to `Android 6.0`?

I am happy to ditch the Huawei EMUI interface if it means a smoother transfer of my account and app settings from the Lollipop phone. I have no data on the Marshmallow phone and I'm happy to do a factory reset if it is required.

I have seen a variety of explanations on line, but many of them are steered toward selling software utilities.

In the past I have found that many core apps such as SMS require the use of additional export / import apps. Others involve copying individual XML files between the phones. I am not expecting that there will be a perfect solution. It would be good if there was a process or product that at least transferred the data, settings and accounts of the 20% of apps that 80% of us use.

What would be the smoothest way to transfer data (SMSes, contacts, photos, emails), accounts (google, email, fb, twitter) and various app settings between these two devices?

Comment: `way to transfer data` what is data here? you mean all your photos, videos, contacts etc. ? `accounts ` what is account? you mean Google Account or WhatsApp Account or Skype Account?

Comment: Yes particularly app settings & deeper data such as SMS, google account etc at the very least..

Comment: i guess for google account, you can always add an account later also, through the Settings app of your new phone. that should fetch all your google account settings easily. i am not sure of `app settings` because its very generic. if you talk specifically about an app, say WhatsApp, then there can be a way. But it will be hard if nothing is specified and people does not know, what and how many apps we are talking about. here

Comment: I've upgraded before & been through a lot of export/import procedures for individual apps (eg SMS).

Comment: So curious as to what current best practice is.

Comment: IMHO i guess u may need to make ur question bit more specific. `app settings` means which app we are talking about? all apps on ur phone? certainly not...Only SMS? certainly not... Spell that out explicitly for any1 to answer it

Comment: I've done as you suggested, & also modifed the question as the source phone has now been updated to Android 6.0.1.

Comment: If you are willing to root both phones safest way is to use Titanium back up. Huawei phones warranty is not voided by rooting, my last phone was a Huawei

Comment: As @beeshyams said, Titanium Backup is the best way out. It needs root, however, and try not to restore **apps** (especially pre-installed system ones) between devices with it (they may not work afterwards). Transferring data, however, should be ok.

Comment: So a basic procedure involving SuperSU would work OK & I presume that the Samsung phone could be unrooted at the end. Assuming that no simpler answer appears, I am happy to award a bounty to an answer with this kind of approach.